# How to run mingw destructors before dll shutdowns

Tags: mingw

I have a fairly simple winsock client program in mingw. I use constructor/destructors to run setup and teardown code before/after the main program runs. As part of the destructor code I call "closesocket()" on the open network connections. The issue is if I exit abnormally, say by control-c, I get the error:

> *** Windows error: WSAStartup cannot function at this time because the underlying system it uses to provide network services is currently
> unavailable.

The message is a bit misleading, because I am not calling WSAStartup (the required startup call for winsock) in the destructor.

What this is telling me is that the winsock dll is being deinitialized before the code gets to my destructor.

Turning the destructor priority all the way up (65535) does not help this.

I am hoping someone more knowledgeable than I for mingw knows how to arrange this.

Answer (score 0):

In MinGW you can use `atexit()` to call a C function that has no parameters.
`WSACleanup()` is such a function, so right after `WSAStartup` you can schedule the cleanup at exit with `atexit(WSACleanup)`.

Comment: Wow, I missed that one. I'll try it and report back on that. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, it runs after the destructor, meaning too late. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `WSAStartup()` should run in the beginning of the program, before any other winsock calls, `WSACleanup()` needs to be called after the last winsock call and before the program finishes.
I don't see why you need to do this in a contructor/destructor. Usually it's okay to to this at the tom of `main()` or `WinMain()`.
Even if you do it in a constructor of some class your program uses, `atexit(WSACleanup)` should still be fine as it cleans up stuff in the winsock stack, not in your class.

Comment: You are correct, and it does work, I tried it. However, that's not what I am talking about. I have had several such shutdown issues with mingw, and it is (obviously IMHO) because there is a bug in how constructors/destructors work in mingw. A constructor, by definition, should run after all of the modules (or dlls) that the program might call have been initialized. Indeed that is why they have a priority. Destructors are the opposite, which is that they should be called BEFORE any code the program calls is deinitialized.

Comment: (cont) this actually does work correctly, for the most part. However, with respect to DLLs it does not. The DLLs used by the program are being shut down before the destructors are called.  This means that any deinit code you put into the destructors that call. directly or indirectly, a dll, cannot work, but rather that code must be put into the end of main() or winmain() (as you stated). I should say this is my theory of what is happening, and obviously I could be wrong. I thought I might post here before digging into the source code for mingw.

Comment: PS moving the priority full up or full down does not help. This leads me to believe (theory again) that the DLLS are shut before the destructor list is even executed. I suspect it is something like "dlls are not part of your program, so we will let them go before executing your shutdown sequence" or similar.

Comment: This one is probably not going to get an answer unless I dig into mingw code. I consider it  to be a bug in mingw at the present time.